# Swap partition on USB Stick

Tags: linux, boot, swap, fstab

I created an additional swap partition on my USB stick and enabled it using `mkswap`. I'd like to have it available upon next boot by adding it to `/etc/fstab`.

But since it's an external USB stick that is being mounted during boot sequence and could possibly be unplugged someday for whatever reason, I'd like to know if this could cause problems, if there's a partition mentioned in `/etc/fstab` that physically may not be available.

Comment: Note that USB sticks have a limited number of write cycles, and the Linux kernel likes to swap out pages in advance if they are not used for some time, so you'll get a large number of not-strictly-necessary writes, which will decrease the lifetime of your USB stick. If you *have* to use an USB stick for swap, consider adjusting `/proc/sys/vm/swappiness` etc. Google for tutorials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you have any "optional" entries, you must mark them with the `nofail` option. That way the boot process will not wait for them to show up.

(With systemd, `nofail` entries will still be activated later, as soon as you plug in the USB stick. Other init systems usually just ignore missing devices entirely.)

Comment: Thank you. I must learn reading the documentation: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab#External_devices

Comment: For anyone coming here (and using systemd), consider using the `x-systemd.device-timeout` - option as described in the documentation.